# Link to Gmail draft now goes to inbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gmail

Starting recently, a link from our site that is supposed to open a draft in Gmail will now redirect to the inbox instead. The draft still exists, and can be navigated to through Gmail, but that extra step is causing delays in our company that relies heavily on sending emails to clients. The code based around it is:

```
def draft_url
   return nil unless from_address

    unless gmail_message_id
      draft = query_gmail_draft
      self.gmail_message_id = draft&.message&.id
    end

    return nil unless gmail_message_id
    "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&Email=#{from_address}&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/u/#{from_address}/%23drafts?compose=#{gmail_message_id}"
end
```

The first part is authentication, but the last link is what takes you to the draft. We did recently update to the newest version of Chrome, but I didn't see anything in the notes that would suggest a change in regard to this.

Comment: Tried this on multiple browsers and get the same issue. It always redirects to the inbox rather than the draft. May be something on Gmail itself?

Comment: I'd be really careful when trying to URL-hack a solution here. Google can and will change their parameter names without warning as well as the names of their endpoints.